# Does the Catalina Music app preserve star ratings from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, migration, ratings

Ever since the introduction of iTunes and the 5-star rating system, I've heavily used the feature to organize my library.

When migrating to Catalina (and thus retiring iTunes), will the star ratings I've set over the last 15+ years be preserved and still usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's disabled by default. I had the exact same question and found the answer [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/443462/where-are-itunes-features-in-macos-catalina/) (screenshots included):

> The Music app won’t show the iTunes Store or your star ratings by default. You can re-enable these features by clicking on Music > Preferences then enabling “iTunes Store” and “Star ratings” on the General tab.

Comment: At least it isn't hidden in a 'defaults write com.apple...' type setting (e.g. half-stars) and is a visible checkbox!